# unfamiliar c language expression, related to pthreads

Tags: c, syntax, boolean, pthreads

Here's a snippet of code. Could someone please explain the last three bool statements. I've never seen that syntax before. I dont know what is going on there. Is it shorthand for something else?

I included the code above the three bool statements to give some context.

```
void *bob;
void *tod;
void *jon;

pthread_t *thrdA= malloc(9 * sizeof(pthread_t));
pthread_t *thrdB= malloc(9 * sizeof(pthread_t));
pthread_t *thrdC = malloc(9 * sizeof(pthread_t));

for(int i = 0; i<9; i++) {
    pthread_create(&thrdA[i], NULL, FUNCT1, (void*)SAS);
}

for(int i = 0; i<9; i++) {
    pthread_create(&thrdB[i], NULL, FUNCT2, (void*)SAS);
}

int x= 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        pthread_create(&thrdC[x], NULL, FUNCT3, (void*)SAS);
        x++;
    }
}
for(int i=0; i<9; i++) {
   pthread_join(thrdA[i], &bob);
   pthread_join(thrdB[i], &tod);
   pthread_join(thrdC[i], &jon);
}    


bool x = (unsigned long)bob== 0;
bool z = (unsigned long)tod== 0;
bool y = (unsigned long)jon== 0;
```

Comment: @AlexF Not wrong, but the implications of the data type of bob should probably be discussed.

Comment: That is mostly due to the fact that pthreads return a void *, so a lot of people needing number-returning threads use them as casted values rather than pointer-to-value.

Answer (score 1):

We would have to see the thread callback to know for sure, but this smells like fishy code passing integers by value by converting to/from `void*`.

Since the pthread callback takes `void*` and returns `void*`, there's apparently lots of strange ideas out there, that these void pointers could as well be used to pass integers by value. That is, cast an integer to/from `void*`, rather than having the pointer point at an allocated object.

Such brittle hacks may have worked by luck when we were still in the 32 bit PC era. Less so nowadays, when x86_64 pointers are typically 64 bits but `int` remains 32 bits.

If the code in question uses such hacks, then that explains the strange and seemingly pointless cast to `unsigned long`.

*Don't* use such crappy hacks, period.

---

Regarding the expression itself: `bob == 0`, this is simple boolean arithmetic. It is perfectly fine to assign the result of equality/relational operators to a `bool` variable. In practice the return type from these operators is `int` in C (unlike C++), but that return type can safely be regarded as type `bool` regardless.

Keep in mind that you have to include stdbool.h to use `bool` - in C that's just a macro for the actual boolean keyword `_Bool`.

Comment: "Crappy hacks" is an inappropriate characterization of the practice you are describing with it.  Although in general, converting an integer (other than an integer constant with value 0) to `void *` and back does have implementation-defined semantics and can produce a trap representation or undefined behavior, the question is about pthreads, which is defined by POSIX for POSIX environments, where conversions of integers not wider that `intptr_t` to a pointer type and back to the same integer type can be relied upon to reproduce the original integer value.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Be that as it may, the potential for bugs because of this hack is great. Suppose for example that there was not a cast back to integer type in main. Then you are suddenly comparing the void pointer against a null pointer representation, which could be anything. Endianess will also cause interesting bug scenarios. The bottom line is that creating a thread is such as expensive operation, that passing a pointer to an object vs a value cast into a pointer is a pre-mature optimization in comparison to the thread creation overhead.

Comment: This ^ conversation is beyond my comprehension. I'm an undergrad student, not an expert

Answer (score 0):

The double equals `==` is a boolean operator e.g.

`if (x==0)`

- if x is zero the statement would evaluate to true
- otherwise the statement would evaluate to false

in other words it is as if you said

`if true` or `if false`

Some C compilers will recognize the bool statement as it is simply a macro (https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/stdbool.h.html).

So essentially, like Alex F said:
x, y, and z are of type bool (they will be recognized as either true or false) based on the return of the boolean expression being evaluated in front of them.  To quote Alex F:
if bob == 0, x = true, else x = false

the (unsigned long) is a type caste